# In SSIS, how to check rows that are following the current one for a calculation?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, rows

I'm currently working on an SSIS project and I need to do something which is a little strange.
I need to check the following rows for NULL/blank values and divide the value across those rows.

[image]

So in this example the rows on the left is the data coming in, I need to divide the value on row 3 across rows 3, 4 and 5, to get rows like on the right.

I'm pretty new to SSIS so I'm really unsure how I would go about doing this. I'm familiar with expressions and script tasks but I'm not entirely sure how I would go about altering multiple rows.
The biggest issue is I don't know how many rows a value may be divided across.

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: what is happening with id 1 and 2? they are both on same data but have different values. Should that be updated to 150 and 150? I would use two passes on this file. 1st pass group by date SUM Money, Count(Date) and then add a derived column Money/Count. Load that into an object. then on 2nd pass use that as a lookup.

Comment: Nothing needs to be done with Id 1 and 2. They are separate. The division only needs to occur if the money column is followed by a NULL.
There is no adding up of the money. Just dividing it across multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this will be that your SSIS data flow will be "blocked".  It cannot process any row of data before all the data is received.
I would load the data in a staging table (with the NULLs) and then run an SQL task with an update statement (to replace the NULLs with a value) and then load the data in your final table.